# How to reduce the height of my div

Tags: html, css

I am now embedded the style tag into my CSS and have also added max-height:90% as suggested but the div element is still overflowing into other elements. what am I doing wrong???

```
<head>
    <style>
        .atlas.region-map
        {
        border: 2px solid #716E64;
        max-width: 500px;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0;
        float: left;
        }

        .atlas.map-content.info-col
        {
        margin-left: 549px;
        width: 335px;
        }
        .atlas.map-content.info-col p
        {
        color: #5c5642;
        margin-top: 15px;
        font-size: 12px;
        }
        .Atlas_Test
        {
        height: 300px;
        font-size: 14px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        max-height: 90%;
        }
       </style>
  </head>

   <body>
    <div class="info-col">
    <p>Content to go here!!!</p>
    </div>
   </body>
```

Comment: info-col class would not be applied to div as its parent does not have   .atlas.map-content class.

Comment: I'm gunna guess that's the issue, unless he did not post the full div structure.

Comment: Please post a complete code example.

Comment: add class with property "clear:both" on the div which is overlapping (the later one usually)..